# Why am I getting error: Initializing Tensorflow?

Tags: android, tensorflow

Im trying to build .apk file by this tutorial - https://www.oreilly.com/learning/tensorflow-on-android

I want to use my own retrained_graph.pb

I change `ClassifierActivity.java` (in tutorial its a `TensorFlowImageListener.java`, but I didnt find this file).
I replaced:

```
private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 299;
private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
private static final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul:0";
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result:0";

private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/retrained_graph.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/retrained_labels.txt";
```

But when I run apk on the device - it crashes with `Error initializing TensorFlow`.

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 6524): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524): Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 6524
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing TensorFlow!
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(ClassifierActivity.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity$1.onPreviewSizeChosen(CameraActivity.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(CameraConnectionFragment.java:394)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.openCamera(CameraConnectionFragment.java:411)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.access$000(CameraConnectionFragment.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraConnectionFragment.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15443)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3506)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16539)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15466)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15488)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:309)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:315)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2956)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2753)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2339)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.tensorflow.Output org.tensorflow.Operation.output(int)' o
W/ActivityManager(  783):   Force finishing activity 1 org.tensorflow.demo/.ClassifierActivity
W/ResourcesManager( 6576): Asset path '/system/framework/sec_platform_library.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager( 6576): Asset path '/system/framework/smatlib.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager( 6576): Asset path '/system/framework/secvisualeffect.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager( 6576): Asset path '/system/framework/sechardware.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
D/InputDispatcher(  783): Focused application set to: xxxx
D/InputDispatcher(  783): Focus left window: 6524
D/PointerIcon(  783): setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001 iconType:101 flag:0 pid:783 uid:1000
D/PointerIcon(  783): setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
```

I found that this code handles exception:

```
@Override
  public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {
    final float textSizePx =
        TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TEXT_SIZE_DIP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    borderedText = new BorderedText(textSizePx);
    borderedText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    try {
      classifier =
          TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(
              getAssets(),
              MODEL_FILE,
              LABEL_FILE,
              INPUT_SIZE,
              IMAGE_MEAN,
              IMAGE_STD,
              INPUT_NAME,
              OUTPUT_NAME);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing TensorFlow!", e);
    }

...

  }
```

in `tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java`

I spent already 2 days, guys help me please! What can be reason of the error?

Comment: Could you re-post the error to include the entire last line? At the moment it stops at `E/AndroidRuntime( 6524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.tensorflow.Output org.tensorflow.Operation.output(int)' o`  which indicates there's something more at the end which may provide some clues.

Comment: @VladB updated!

Comment: There should be even more context above the section you posted that would help analyze the problem. Anything that gets logged with "adb logcat *:E *:tensorflow *:native" could be useful.

Comment: @AndrewHarp link to the whole log https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwelux41gs0pvqj/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Based on the documentation for `NullPointerException`: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html , I would put some breakpoint in the `onPreviewSizeChosen` function and check that all the required parameters are not null.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @chengsam no, still have the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, the comment in the java code is not updated, now just change:

```
private static final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul:0";
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result:0";
```

To:

```
private static final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul";
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
```

Comment: You made my day! Thank you

Comment: Below is the command you issue in cmd:

    `python freeze_graph.py --input_graph=graph.pbtxt --input_binary=false --input_checkpoint=model.ckpt-1500 --output_graph=frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=softmax_tensor --inputs='Mul' --outputs='softmax_tensor'`

If you want to get names of inputs and outputs, and not sure if it is 'Mul' and 'final_result', open your graph.pb file in Tensorflow:


  [link]: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz